# Set Html.BeginForm action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

The razor helper is not resolving the correct action to submit form.

### How can I set the correct Action in the Razor helper?

---

So I have the following actions on my `PortfolioController`:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("profile/edit", Name = "edit-profile")]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditPortfolioViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

And my form is like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Portfolio", FormMethod.Post, ...)
```

But the form action is being resolved as:

```
<form action="/profile/edit" ...>
```

Instead of

```
<form action="/Portfolio/Edit" ...>
```

I know I could simply change the Action method names, but I would like to keep their names.

Comment: Why do you want /profile/edit to post to /portfolio/edit? Seems a little unusual when you could apply the same route to the post action and have consistency between the get/post actions

Comment: @finman My route on this code is just a sample, in my projetct is in portuguese to make url friendly. But action methods is a overload like the default MVC code. One for the view and another to receive the form.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `[ActionName("")]` attribute to change the action name to your desired name

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("profile/edit"]
[ActionName("edit-profile")]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    ...
}
```

and your route Begin form will be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("edit-profile", "Portfolio", FormMethod.Post, ...)
```

Comment: This will still resolve the form action to "profile/edit"

Answer (score 0):

Recreated it on a new project, looks like the expected behaviour for the routing to defer which route it uses to the get action so it posts to the same action name (which would make sense as the routing table has no concept of HTTP methods). Adding a new route on the post action will not help.